# Differentiation under integral sign proof

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I tried to prove :

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{h(x)}^{g(x)} f(t)dt=f(x,g(x))g'(x)-f(x,h(x))h'(x)$$

Let anti derivative of $f(t)$  be $F(t)$ So by FTC

$$\int_{h(x)}^{g(x)} f(t)dt=F(g(x))-F(h(x))$$ and differentiating both sides and using chain Rule we get

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{h(x)}^{g(x)} f(t)dt=f(g(x))g'(x)-f(h(x))h'(x)$$ But can i get any hint to prove the more stronger version:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{h(x)}^{g(x)} f(x,t)dt=f(x,g(x))g'(x)-f(x,h(x))h'(x)+\int_{h(x)}^{g(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t)dt$$

Comment: Just use the FTC again, letting $F(x,t)$ be an anti-derivative relative to $t$.

Comment: I'm confused, in your first equation you have $f(t)$ and $f(x,g(x))$.  Does $f$ take one or two parameters?

Comment: @copper.hat, I edited it thanks

Comment: I still don't understand, in the first equation $f$ takes one parameter in one instance and two parameters in the other.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Define $\varphi(x) = \int_{g(x)}^{h(x)} f(x,t)\,dt$. For $\Delta x > 0$, define $\Delta g = g(x + \Delta x) - g(x), \Delta h = h(x + \Delta x) - h(x)$. Explicitly calculate $\Delta \varphi = \varphi(x + \Delta x) - \varphi(x)$ and use the mean value theorem
$$ \exists g(x) < \tau < h(x)\mid \int_{g(x)}^{h(x)} f(t)\,dt = (h(x) - g(x)) f(\tau)
$$

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to prove first the following (ideally, you have seen it in class):

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_a^b f(x,t) dx= \int_a^b \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(x,t) dx.$$

This is proven by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, after using Fubini's theorem. If the integrand of the r.h.s. is assumed to be a continuous function (on both variables), you can apply the FTC and the rest, no problem.

Then your version would be to consider $H(a,b,t)=\int_a^b f(x,t) dx$ and to apply the chain rule to $H(h(t), g(t), t).$   The result will be plain.

Hope this helps.